# Make Javascript document.write with script tag Block

Tags: javascript, blocking, document.write

Does anyone know how I can make document.write with a script tag block execution?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var test = "bad";
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="js.php"><\/script>');
    console.log(test);
</script>
```

Where js.php is

```
<?PHP sleep(1); echo "var test='good';"; ?>
```

console.log should output "good", but it outputs "bad". Of course, after a second, the var does change to "good", but I definitely need it to be blocking. Thanks!!

I kind of see whats happening. It looks like any document.write in the current script block actually gets written right *after* the current script block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do an Ajax call to load more data. It is unlikely for this to be customizable. You can easily do that with jQuery and JSON.

Comment: You can define a callback to start your script only after the ajax call is completed. You can also add some "Loading" animation for your website while the ajax call takes place and remove it in the callback.

Comment: @nolanpro XHR can also be blocking, using the (a)synchronous flag of the XMLHttpRequest object. It's the third parameter of the `open` method. That's one of the reasons why 'AJAX' is not the right term for XHR by the way.

Comment: Thanks I think that will work! I can't use jQuery unfortunately because of the specific implementation, but XHR like Kooilnc said could be the tick.

Answer (score 2):

I seem to recall there being a workaround for writing `<script>` tags:

```
document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="js.php"><\/scr'+'ipt>');
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work. I'm using chrome & firefox. Thanks anyway though!